# react sometimes not rendering dom when scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, dom, semantic-ui

I have a react app that can add object from list A to list B
however, the object in list A can be too many, therefor, I shrink the container and add overflow=true css style so that the container can be scrolled

However, sometimes, the DOM is not rendering
like this:

[image: not rendering]

but if I click or interact with the DOM object (the object is an accordion in this case), it will re-appear

[image: correct]

how to fix this annoying bug?
I am using the latest chrome browser, with semantic ui as css framework

Comment: Sample code please.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Running into the same thing today.